# Firebase notifications with app closed not triggering correct behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a firebase messing service class that handles data notifications when app is running or in the background. I am able to show notifications in the bar when app is running or not.

I have different behaviours for different notifications, and onMessageReceived handles the fragment that I will be launching.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    ...
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        ...
        // redirect to specific chat or chat list if we have messages from several conversations
        if (conversation_id.compareTo("") == 0 ||
          (conversation_id.compareTo(newConversationID) == 0 && classRedir == FragmentChat.class)) {
            classRedir = FragmentChat.class;
            conversation_id = newConversationID;
        }
        else {
            classRedir = FragmentChatList.class;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The main problem is that this redirection only works if I click the notification and the app is running. If not, when I click the notification, the app simply starts lauching the splash screen and going to the user's default screen.

I can see that within the extras inside the splash screen I have what appears to be the content of the notification, as it includes all the fields that I need.

My question is: How should I instruct firebase messaging service to process any potential existing messages when the application starts? Or am I looking into this the wrong way?

Thank you.

Comment: so you want to go to a certain activity(always that activity?) when clicking the notification?

Comment: @PeterHaddad that is exactly what I need, and it works correctly if the app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it, after a lot of banging my head against the wall.

I added the following to my splash fragment, not sure if this is the more elegant way to do it:

```
// check if we came from a notification click
            if (extras.containsKey(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CONVERSATION_ID)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "initialize: captured extra from notification ");

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString(Constants.EXTRA_CHAT_CONVERSATION_ID, extras.getString(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CONVERSATION_ID));

                Intent intent = NavigationManager.getIntent(getContext(), ActivityMain.class, FragmentChat.class, bundle);

                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
```